# Github Pages - processing Jekyll content w/o running Jekyll locally?

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm trying the waters with Github pages, and (at the machine I'm trapped at for the moment) can't install Jekyll locally.  The impression I get from the documentation is that I should just be able to write the Jekyll template commands into the content, and Github will know what to do as the commits come in.

However, that doesn't seem to be happening.

Specifically, I added: `_includes/header.html`:

```
<ul>
  <li id="home_page">Home</li>
  <li id="other_page">Other Stuff</li>
</ul>
```

and then in root `index.html`:

```
<body>
{% include header.html %}
<p>helloworld</p>
</body>
```

but when I go that page, it shows the include statement, instead of the processed page.  I am working in the gh-pages branch (and have that set to default).

What other steps do I need to take to actually have Github process the templates?

Comment: Are you pushing to the right branches? https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#setting-the-domain-in-your-repo

Comment: I'm just trying to serve it straight from username.github.io/project_name, not anything fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered via asking Github support:

Files for Jekyll processing actually *are* unique.  [They need to have a YAML block at the beginning, even if that block is empty](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).  So, the above code basically needed

```
---  <-- these two lines of dashes are
---  <-- important
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% include header.html %}
<p>some edit? helloworld</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include those two lines of dashes `---` before starting a document that you'd like to be processed by Jekyll. If you do not, Jekyll simply copies your files as it is and does not run the commands.

You can specify different parameters between those dashes, like title, description, date, tags, categories etc etc.